# error running gem install pg -v '0.15.1'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pg, linux-mint

Running

```
gem install pg -v '0.15.1'
```

giving errors:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing pg:    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>     /home/askar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby extconf.rb checking for pg_config... no No pg_config... trying anyway. If
> ```
>
> building fails, please try again with 
>   --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config checking for libpq-fe.h... no Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:   --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
>     --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>     --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
>     --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir
>     --ruby=/home/askar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby     --with-pg
>     --without-pg    --with-pg-dir   --without-pg-dir    --with-pg-include
>     --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include  --with-pg-lib
>     --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib  --with-pg-config    --without-pg-config
>     --with-pg_config    --without-pg_config
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/pg-0.15.1 for inspection.
>   Results logged to
>   /home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/pg-0.15.1/ext/gem_make.out

I'm using

1. Rails 4.0.0.rc1
2. Ruby 1.9.3-p429
3. Linux Mint Nadia v 14

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to install a native extension for the `pg` gem.

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```